# If the value of Coulombs Constant is high, What can we conclude about the Electric force?

Tags: electrostatics, dimensional-analysis, coulombs-law, physical-constants

I wondered about that question and regardless of the obvious answer (If $k$ increases, the Electrostatic force increases), What can we conclude from $||\vec{F}_e||$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to keep the speed of light constant, then increasing Coulomb's constant $k = (4\pi\epsilon_0)^{-1}$ effectively increases the fine structure constant

$$
\alpha = \frac{k e^2}{\hbar c}
$$
Where $e$ is the electron charge. You could actually think of increasing $k$ as increasing the "charge" $\sqrt{k} e$.

The current value of $\alpha$ (at low energies) is small -- approximately $1/137$. This means that quantum effects, which appear as corrections to the classical theory in increasing powers of $\alpha$, are *small*. This means that we can trust Maxwell's equations and classical electromagnetism to give us a very good, zeroth order approximation to electromagnetic phenomena.

You have some room to increase $k$ (and therefore $\alpha$) without changing this qualitative picture. Generally electromagnetism would behave in a simliar way to the way it ordinarily, "just" with bigger charges. However, this could have interesting consequences for our world. For example, atoms would become smaller (for example, the [Bohr radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius) $\sim 1/(\alpha m_e)$ would become smaller), chemical bonds would become stronger, various reaction rates could change. Even though the qualitative picture of electromagnetism would be simliar to what we have now, one shouldn't assume that every aspect of the physical world would be unchanged; there are interesting facets of our Universe like the [Hoyle state](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/hoyle-state-primordial-nucleus-behind-elements-life/), which is necessary for the production of Carbon in stars (and therefore of the Carbon that forms the basis of life on Earth), that seem to depend sensitively on the balance between different reaction rates, and might change if the constants were shifted from their original value. (I am not saying that the Hoyle state would stop existing if you changed Coulomb's constant -- I'm not sure -- I'm just using this as an example that once you start changing reaction rates of different processes, you can get unexpectedly different qualitative behavior in a system).

However, if you make $\alpha$ large enough that it becomes of order $1$, so that increasing powers of $\alpha$ do not get smaller (ie, $\alpha^2$ is not much less than $\alpha$, $\alpha^3$ is not much less than $\alpha^2$, and so on), then quantum effects *will* become important, and we can't trust our intuition that comes from treating Maxwell's equations classically. At this point, it becomes very difficult to predict what will happen. The situation is like [QCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics), where analytic calculations are impossible, and a combination of experiments, toy models, and numerics are needed to understand what is going on.

Interestingly, if the fine structure constant becomes very big (much bigger than one), and if magnetic monopoles exist, then one might be able to use [electromagnetic duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montonen%E2%80%93Olive_duality) to understand what is going on.

Comment: This is just a fantastic response. Thanks mate.